# unable to fetch the response from the backend: malformed MIME header: missing colon: %!!(MISSING)q(MISSING)[info]

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5

всем привет, установила
symfony new project
у меня возникло две проблемы:

отсутствуют стили на стартовой странице, нет привычной фиолетово-зеленой стартовой странице, просто код html, css
это меня напугало и я решила вывести хоть что-то из контроллера , например, подгрузила данный код :

```
     <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="color:red">HELLO</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

и тут неожиданно вылезает вторая ошибка, которая напугала меня еще больше:

**# unable to fetch the response from the backend: malformed MIME header: missing colon: %!!(MISSING)q(MISSING)[info] Matched route "hello".**

пожалуйста, помогите, кто сталкивался

Comment: пробовала прописывать руты в конфигах, не помогло((

Comment: Какую версию symfony используете? Какой сервер используете для запуска?